# Java 2d RPG game with multiplayer support

Tags: java, client-server, 2d

I want to make an top-down RPG game, with multiplayer support for up to 4 players. I have no need for graphics right now, the map can be a  black grid and the player a red dot.
The game features are:
A 10000*10000 map that will feature some treasure chests, which will give stat boost
each player will have the basic rpg stats(attk,def,speed,etc) which he should be able to divide 30 points on each of these before the game starts.
The players will move real time using the arrow keys.
Each player will have a visible field of view of 20*20.
If a player comes in proximity of 5*5 or closer to another player there will be a battle which will compare the stats along with some dice rolls.
The game must have a pause feature and also a lobby feature.

The game must be in Java
The reason i am asking is because i have very limited knowledge on the way of programming such a project, and the guides i have found on youtube mostly are two complicated because of graphics or do not support the multiplayer feature.
I would like if this community could give me some directions about how I should start this game, or better if they could give me the link to some internet tutorial/video or book that can teach me the things I need to finish this. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE7ezYCTPe4&list=ELp5mgUw5g9EY) is how my good friend learned java development. Obviously you're not going to find any tutorial that follow your exact needs, but this one is semi-close. I believe it goes into networking later in the series. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dzhgsVaiSo) is also very good, but it is farther away from your specifications. Another, better thing you can do is follow [simpler tutorials](http://www.cokeandcode.com/info/tut2d.html) until you know what you are doing, then change the source around to fit your specifications.

Generally if you do not know any java at all, starting with a game like this is not a very good idea. But if you are very motivated, it can be done.

By the way, this broad type of question is not very well suited for a Q & A site like this, so expect downvotes from others unless you edit your question.